# Could not find class 'com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfReader'

Tags: android, pdf, itext, sign

I created an android application which sign a pdf file using iText. The project runs perfectly fine on API levels, but, I'm getting some problems on emulators. When I load up the application on an emulator, I get this problem:

```
02-21 20:51:52.368: E/dalvikvm(410): Could not find class 'com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfReader', referenced from method com.exampl.exemp.Sign_pdf.signPdf
02-21 20:51:52.368: W/dalvikvm(410): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 26 (Lcom/lowagie/text/pdf/PdfReader;) in Lcom/exampl/exemp/Sign_pdf;
02-21 20:51:52.378: D/dalvikvm(410): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x004a
02-21 20:51:52.398: D/dalvikvm(410): VFY: dead code 0x004c-0095 in Lcom/exampl/exemp/Sign_pdf;.signPdf ()Z
02-21 20:51:57.187: I/dalvikvm(410): Total arena pages for JIT: 11
02-21 20:51:57.227: I/dalvikvm(410): Total arena pages for JIT: 12
02-21 20:51:57.487: D/AndroidRuntime(410): Shutting down VM
02-21 20:51:57.497: W/dalvikvm(410): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
02-21 20:51:57.517: E/AndroidRuntime(410): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-21 20:51:57.517: E/AndroidRuntime(410): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfReader
02-21 20:51:57.517: E/AndroidRuntime(410):  at com.exampl.exemp.Sign_pdf.signPdf(Sign_pdf.java:47)
02-21 20:51:57.517: E/AndroidRuntime(410):  at com.exampl.exemp.MainActivity.editText(MainActivity.java:114)
02-21 20:51:57.517: E/AndroidRuntime(410):  at com.exampl.exemp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:36)
02-21 20:51:57.517: E/AndroidRuntime(410):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
02-21 20:51:57.517: E/AndroidRuntime(410):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
02-21 20:51:57.517: E/AndroidRuntime(410):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
02-21 20:51:57.517: E/AndroidRuntime(410):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
02-21 20:51:57.517: E/AndroidRuntime(410):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
02-21 20:51:57.517: E/AndroidRuntime(410):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-21 20:51:57.517: E/AndroidRuntime(410):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-21 20:51:57.517: E/AndroidRuntime(410):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
02-21 20:51:57.517: E/AndroidRuntime(410):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-21 20:51:57.517: E/AndroidRuntime(410):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-21 20:51:57.517: E/AndroidRuntime(410):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
02-21 20:51:57.517: E/AndroidRuntime(410):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
02-21 20:51:57.517: E/AndroidRuntime(410):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-21 20:56:57.660: I/Process(410): Sending signal. PID: 410 SIG: 9
```

The problem maybe is comming up with the iText jar so what is the compatible version with android.
Any help greatly appreciated...

Comment: Clean your project once, also check you have included the library if there is any.

Comment: Is this lib set for Export in Build Path?

Comment: @Rajesh CP I do it but the issue still !!

Comment: @nikis yes this lib set for Export in Build Path

Comment: The Android version of iText doesn't have any packages that are named after me. Please use iTextG instead of what you're using now: http://itextpdf.com/product/itextg

Comment: @Bruno Lowagie I use the right jars of SpongyCastle (scprov-jdk15on and scpkix-jdk15on) and iTextG for Android (itextg-5.5.0) but the problem still. Can you me explain what do you mean by this note:Concerning the use of iTextG on Google App Engine: Refrain from using the constructor of PdfReader that uses a path.

Comment: Google App Engine has no file system, so there is no such thing as a path. Why are you asking? You're using Android, aren't you? If so, you shouldn't worry about GAE.

Comment: As for your question, please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16841050/could-not-find-class and if that doesn't work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745198/could-not-find-class-when-application-is-loaded-into-emulator

Comment: @Bruno Lowagie thanks for answers. Yes I use Android. But when I added the jars of SpongyCastle(scprov-jdk15on and scpkix-jdk15on) I get this error in the LogCat "Could not find class 'org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSEnvelopedData', referenced from method com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfReader.readDecryptedDocObj"

Comment: Another when I use jars of iTextG for Android(itextg-5.5.0) the project compiles with errors(cannot use the imports) but with iText-2.1.7 no erreur just in the LogCat (Could not find class 'org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSEnvelopedData', referenced from method com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfReader.readDecryptedDocObj)

Comment: The imports when using iTextG are com.itextpdf instead of com.lowagie!

Comment: Also: you are mixing BouncyCastle and SpongyCastle. It's as if you're not reading the documentation: you can't use iText 2.1.7 because of its dependency on BouncyCastle!

Comment: @Bruno I use the jars (iTextG and SpongyCastle) which you tell me but I still get an error in this line 'sap.setCrypto(key, (java.security.cert.Certificate[]) chain, null, PdfSignatureAppearance.SELF_SIGNED);' SELF_SIGNED cannot be resolved or is not a field.

Comment: I posted my question here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21886800/self-signed-cannot-be-resolved-or-is-not-a-field]